# How to show validation summary that corresponds exactly to the form submitted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-binding

The same problem is discussed in this post: [Multiple forms in MVC view: ModelState applied to all forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102918/multiple-forms-in-mvc-view-modelstate-applied-to-all-forms).

I have followed along the post and also have several forms on the same view, custom editor template, have created and registered custom model binder. [Here is the accompanying gist](https://gist.github.com/happygrizzly/25447f1b46a6b4116ff8).

When I use the `Html.ValidationResultFor()` helpers in the **PasswordEditorViewModel.cshtml editor template** I get the desired results:

```
<li class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.OldPassword)</li>
<li class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.NewPassword)</li>
<li class="error">@Html.ValidationMessage("PasswordChangeError.WrongPassword")</li>
```

This code returns validation errors exactly for the form I've posted.

On the other hand when I use the `Html.ValidationSummary()` helper in the same editor template the validation result is propagated across all forms despite the fact I've posted only one:

[image]

Is this a normal behavior? Or have I missed something in the code?

Answer (score 1):

When using @Html.ValidationSummary, it does not remember which from was posted, and by which submit button. The way I have handled this in the past is having

```
<input type="submit" value="button1" />
@if (Request["button1"] != null)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}

<input type="submit" value="button2" />
@if (Request["button2"] != null)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```