# ModelState applied to all forms in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, modelstate

I am experiencing an issue where the model state is being applied to every form that exists on a single page. For example, if validation is not met e.g. the user doesn't complete a required field, then the message ' x field is required' is applied to every form after post back. The page has two 'different' (but exactly the same) forms on it

- comment reply form (sits after every comment and can occur x amount of times)
- new comment reply form (sits at the bottom of all the comments and exists once)

I am building up a comments section where foreach comment a user can leave a comment, this means that the comment reply form can exist x amount of times, if there are 10 comments then it will be on the page 10 times.

I have the following (scaled down for explanation purposes) code

Model

```
public string FullName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
```

View

```
@model BlogCommentsViewModel

// when this is pressed use js to show the form
<button type="button" id="form-toggle-btn" class="btn btn-md btn-primary-filled js-reply-comment-button">
    <strong>REPLY <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
</button>

@foreach (var item in Model.BlogComments)
{   
  ///blog comment markup here
             
   div class="reply-comment-form js-reply-comment-form">

@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<BlogCommentSurfaceController>("CreateComment", null, new { id = "reply-form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { placeholder = "Full Name", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FullName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment, new { placeholder = "Message", @class = "form-control", @rows = 7 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comment)
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="form-reply-submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary-filled btn-form-submit">
            <strong>POST REPLY</strong>
        </button>

    </div>

}                                        
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(BlogCommentViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || model == null)
       return CurrentUmbracoPage();                 

       return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

A form only shows when the 'post reply button is pressed, I use a small bit of JS with some CSS to show\hide a form' The problem I have, if validation fails it applies to all forms on the page. This is using jquery unobtrusive on the clientside

[image]

How can I restrict this to only the form that is interacted with ?

I read this which feels similar [Multiple forms in MVC view: ModelState applied to all forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102918/multiple-forms-in-mvc-view-modelstate-applied-to-all-forms)

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: I can see you have created a form inside a loop so here multiple form tags created correctly?

Comment: Yes that's correct for every loop there will be a form (with form tag) if I loop 10 times for 10 comments then there will be 10 form tags. I tried creating a random guid and assigning a unique id but it didn't make a difference. Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like the validators are working as expected. You are outputting the same field for the same model several times (regardless of whether it's inside a loop and  different forms). The link you provided yourself is giving you a way to make this work. What's the mystery here?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, it's validating as expecting but it's validating every form instance which I wasn't expecting, I was expecting it to only care about the form in scope. I agree this is likely because all the properties have the same name. I tried changing the form model names but that didn't work. The mystery is my lack of understanding hence my turning to this forum. I had an incline that the link I posted maybe a possible workaround but I wasn't sure if I could apply it to my scenario and it all feels overkill to what I'm trying to achieve here!